# How to insert test data into H2 using sequence for default value, when Hibernate entity has GenerationType.SEQUENCE

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, h2

When an entity is mapped with GenerationType.IDENTITY an sql insert into a h2 test db will have a default value for the id column pointing to a sequence. When mapped with GenerationType.SEQUENCE it won't have a default value.

We want to use GenerationType.SEQUENCE as it's more verbose and we want to show where everything comes from. During testing we've stumbled upon this problem - when using @Sql to insert a script into an embedded h2 database we get an error about a not null constraint.It also happens when we just execute the script as a native query.

This doesn't happen when using GenerationType.IDENTITY. The same script from above works properly.

If we use GenerationType.SEQUENCE and pass it the id by calling a next value function like this:

```
INSERT INTO example (id, name) (NEXTVAL('example_id_seq'), 'test');
```

the script will work without a problem.

Here is an example mapping an insert where the problem occurs:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = DbSchemas.PUBLIC, name = DbTables.Example)
public class Example implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8827852720381659873L;

private static final String EXAMPLE_GENERATOR = "example_generator";

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = EXAMPLE_GENERATOR)
@SequenceGenerator(name = EXAMPLE_GENERATOR, sequenceName = DbSequences.EXAMPLE_ID_SEQUENCE, allocationSize = 1)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;

}
```

---

```
INSERT INTO public.example (name) 
VALUES ('test');
```

---

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
```

I'd like to be able to call the insert shown above for entities mapped with GenerationType.SEQUENCE. The insert must use and increment the sequence described in the mapping.

Comment: No, example_generator is just the name of the generator with define in @SequenceGenerator
The name of the actual sequence is example_id_seq. It is a property of the example_generator

Comment: rgr, sry, forget my comment

Comment: +1, same problem. I would like hibernate to generate DDL for the ID column as DEFAULT mysequence.nextval.  How can I achieve this?